# How can I use 1 notifyIcon between multiple forms?

Tags: c#, forms, class, notifyicon, instantiation

I have a notifyIcon added to my main form of a project. I have other forms in the project that I want to be able to use the notifyIcon though which is proving difficult. What would be the best way to use 1 notifyIcon between multiple forms? I read a thread about not adding it to a form but instantiating it in its own class which made no sense to me. Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just expose a property on your main form to return a reference to the NotifyIcon.  You can even make it static since there is only ever one:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form {
    public MainForm() {
        InitializeComponent();
        notifier = this.notifyIcon1;
        this.FormClosed += delegate { notifier = null; };
    }

    public static NotifyIcon Notifier { get { return notifier; } }

    private static NotifyIcon notifier;
}
```

Code in other classes can now simply use MainForm.Notifier.

Comment: I'm getting an error using MainForm: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: I implemented your code above, and within the form I need to use the notifyIcon1 I used the code:  Form1.Notifier.BalloonTipText = "Balloon text"; Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Create a public static variable in the Form where `NotifyIcon` is implemented:

```
public static NotifyIcon m_objNotifyIcon;
```

in form load assign forms `NotifyIcon`:

```
m_objNotifyIcon = this.notifyIcon1;
```

all set. Now you can access the notify icon from anywhere in the project

```
Forms.MainScreen.m_objNotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(2000, "Title", "Message", ToolTipIcon.Info);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you need to assign `MainForm` to `NotifyIcon` control, don't see any problem about sharing it's object between different forms.

Let's say, to try to be more clear:

**1.** `MainForm` starts and initializes `NotifyIcon` control wrapper class, let's call `NotifyControlHolder`.

**2.** That `NotifyControlHolder` class stands in your `UIShared` like a public property.

**3.** `UIShared` singletone class is accesible from differnt parts of your application, which can access it and change it's state, bypassing the `MainForm`.

Comment: I am still pretty novice at this stuff Tigran. Though I think I understand what you're saying I'm having a difficult time knowing how to implement it.